# Spring Integration call Web service

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm still new to Spring Integration and I've few question.

I have a service with WSDL deploy in tomcat server.

and I would like to send parameter from my spring integration flow to that service and receive 
response back to do next things in the flow.

I should use outbound WS gateway to do this right? 
and how to config the xml to do this?

i've try temperature example but still don't understand it.

thank you.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Here is my config:

```
     <int:gateway service-interface="com.app.service.IRequester" id="IRequester"
    default-request-channel="requestChannel"  
    default-reply-channel="responseChannel"
    error-channel="errorChannel" >
 </int:gateway>

 <int:service-activator input-channel="requestChannel" id="bu1"
     ref="BU1" method="bu1Method"
     output-channel="buChannel">
</int:service-activator>

 <int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" 
      ref="handlerError" method="errorReturnToGateway"
      output-channel="responseChannel" >
  </int:service-activator>

 <int:router id="routingChannel" input-channel="buChannel" ref="RoutingChannel"     method="routingChannel">
     <int:mapping value="firstChannel" channel="channelFirst" />
     <int:mapping value="otherChannel" channel="channelOther" />
 </int:router>

 <int:service-activator id="firstBU" input-channel="channelFirst"
        ref="FirstBU" method="doSomething" output-channel="responseChannel">
 </int:service-activator>
 <int:service-activator id="otherBU" input-channel="channelOther"
        ref="OtherBU" method="doSomething" output-channel="responseChannel">
 </int:service-activator>
```

I need to change output channel from both firstBU and otherBU activator to call web service  which is send a paremeter to that service(paremeter type is Hashmap) and  receive same type response.

I don't know how to call web service by using ws:outbound-gateway.Since I have only known to call web service using java way by generate client java class and may be i'll call service in method doSomething.

In my case,Do you think which way is better?
And I still want to know how to solve this by use ws:outbound-gateway too.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as it is SOAP, so you get deal with XML. And your WSDL provides you the contract - an XSD which XML should be sent to the service and which will be returned as a response.

So, your task to configure `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` and provide correct XML as a message `payload` to the `request-channel` of that component.

The same is about a response: you get an XML as `payload`.

However, it is for **simple** WS Outbound Gateway. You can configure it with `marshaller` and send to the `request-channel` some domain POJO and that `marshaller` takes care about converting that POJO to the XML representation for the SOAP request.

Show, your config, please, and maybe we can help more with your concreate issues.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have finish update config in my topic post.

Comment: If you dont' have enough time, you can go ahead with code generation and use generic `<service-activator>`. Otherwise you need to study what is `Contract First` and how Spring WS implement it. Spring Integration WS module is fully based on Spring WS project.

Comment: Thank you again,The code generation way is working fine and I'll study about Spring WS as you suggest too.